# 2 iframes on the page display the same content when they shouldn't

Tags: youtube-iframe-api

I need to display two iFrames on the same page with different content:

- one with YouTube video
- the second one with a Google Docs form

but when I insert the second iFrame it displays the same content as the first one.
Am I missing something?

Comment: could you share some code so the community can help you?

Comment: yes, but it contains nothing special^:

`<iframe width="640" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/3Ku5X7UxG4c" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfCRC4Pvr_jhiYW_ckJMy40DCLQ1gMsvuJfLFN20sK7h5yYCw/viewform?embedded=true" width="500" height="820" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">Загрузка...</iframe>`

iframes are located in different divs

Comment: sorry, I think the bug is somewhere in html or css of the page, but I can not finde where - on the other page everything works without problem.

Can somebody help me to find the bug here wd2018.protivgepatita.ru